# Problems to insert comma in each element in a list in python

Tags: python, list, split

Hy friends,
I would like to make a code to split each element in python, but it does not work.

the code:

```
def insert(string):
    li = list(string.split(','))
    return li
   

num1 = str(input("Past the list: "))
insert(num1)
```

the list:

```
20,Amsterdam,B,Right,1  
131,Hungry,B,Left,1  
0.70,NY,B,Left,1  
1.23,USA,D,Right,1  
1.47,Montreal,D,Right,1
```

the results:

```
['20', 'Amsterdam', 'B', 'Right', '1 131', 'Hungry', 'B', 'Left',  '1 0.70', 'NY', 'B', 'Left',
 '1 1.23', 'USA', 'D', 'Right', '1 1.47', 'Montreal', 'D',  'Right', '1']
```

it should be:

```
['20', 'Amsterdam', 'B', 'Right', '1', '131', 'Hungry', 'B', 'Left',  '1', '0.70', 'NY', 'B', 'Left', '1', '1.23', 'USA', 'D', 'Right', '1', '1.47', 'Montreal', 'D',  'Right', '1']
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the result of `split` to `list`.  It's already a list, so passing it to `list` just results in an unnecessary copy.

Comment: `input` should read a single line.  How are you entering multiple lines, and what are you passing to `insert`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but every day I need to split huge lists, if you noticed the problem is  in the end of each row because my code joins the end of the row with the beginning of the other one, for example, '1 131'. And I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Well, the end of line character is `\n` and as it is not a `,`, it is not *split*

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle newline/whitespace characters:

```py
import re

def insert(string):
    return re.sub(r"\s+", ',', string, flags=re.M).split(',')


num1 = str(input("Past the list: "))
insert(num1)
```

For just newlines and not other whitespace: `re.sub(r"\n+", ',', string, flags=re.M).split(',')`